# How to Remove menu item in Odoo9?

Tags: odoo, odoo-9

How to remove the menu items from the dropdown menu on the top right, I want to remove `About`, `Documentation`, `Support` and `My Odoo.com account`.

I tried installing the `disable_openerp_online-8.0.1.1.0` module but it is for version 8 which does not work on version 9.....

Comment: Can someone please tell me where the placement of these items is actually done the `user_menu.js` is the working as mention but still i can see the `About` and other items on it but upon clicking nothing happens...

Comment: Or if i can change the contents of `About` Will also do.

Answer (score 2):

Try to see the following file:

```
web/static/src/xml/base.xml
```

You will find a template named '**UserMenu**'.
Try to inherit it and remove the contents you needed to remove.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at `web/static/src/js/widgets` and the file is `user_menu.js` is the working of...

Comment: But where can i find the placement of these menus ? so i can remove it altogether ?